# Starting question with "has"

Tags: tense, questions, auxiliary-verbs, headlinese

What is the difference between **Has he come?** and **Did he come?**

Is the headline of [the linked article](https://theaviationist.com/?p=42001) correct?

Comment: For those confused (as I was) by the headline, "Combat Sent" is the name  of the aircraft -- it's an *RC-135U 'Combat Sent' signal intelligence aircraft*. So the question is whether the headline *Has an [A] "covered" the two [B] visiting Estonia?* is grammatically correct.

Comment: *Has he come* suggests that he is still here. *Did he come* suggests that he might already have been and left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the question form of sentence that use the perfect tense:

> He went to Morocco.
>   Did he go to Morocco?

vs.

> He has been to Morocco
>   Has he been to Morocco?

In the same way:

> (This) aircraft has covered (those) aircraft.
>   Has (this) aircraft covered (those) aircraft?

The present perfect form indicates "life experience", although in this case it's not referring to any specific person's life but rather the *general* existence of some experience/event.  The meaning is to suggest some experience *did* happen.

As you expect, it would have been more straightforward to simply ask, "Did aircraft A cover aircraft B & C?" but "has" still gets the meaning across.

Side note:  Here "covered" means "to provide support in the form of 'radar coverage'", although in this case it seems perhaps the "spy" aircraft were used to *deter* the Russians from using their own radar to track the stealth fighters?  Something like that.  The language is full of military jargon and is slightly confusing.